# NHibernate: Any way to generate a 1-based sequence number for every child object?

Tags: nhibernate, indexing, mapping, one-to-many

**My classes:**

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
        /* other properties */
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Parent Mother { get; set; }
        public virtual int ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string Remarks { get; set; }
        /* other properties */
    }
```

**My DB:**

```
PARENTS(ID, NAME, ...) -> PRIMARY KEY = ID
CHILDREN (C_ID, MOTHER_ID, ITEM_NO, REMARKS ....) -> PRIMARY KEY = c_ID
```

**NHibernate Mapping:**

```
  <class name="Parent" table="PARENTS">
        <id name="Id"  column="ID">
          <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="NAME"/>
        <list name="Children" cascade="all" inverse="true">
        <key column="MOTHER_ID" not-null="true" />
           <list-index base="1" column="ITEM_NO"/>
          <one-to-many class="Child" />
        </list>
 </class>

  <class name="Child" table="CHILDREN">
        <id name="Id"  column="C_ID">
          <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="Mother" class="Parent" column="MOTHER_ID" />
        <property name="ItemNumber" column="ITEM_NO"/> 
        <property name="Remarks" column="REMARKS"/>
 </class>
```

**My Code:**

```
Parent p = new Parent();
//set parent properties here
Child c = new Child();
//set child properties here

p.Children.add(c);
c.Mother = p;

//Save parent
```

**Question:**

The above code saves the parent as well as all children in the respective tables. However, all the children have the default value zero in the field ITEM_NO. Is there any mapping that can help me to automatically assign a progressively incremental value to ITEM_NO starting with 1 for each children of a given parent? i.e the sequence for ITEM_NO should repeat from 1 to the number of children for each Parent.

NB: I need Child to be an independent entity, so I should be able to query it without necessariry going through the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the insert="true" in the list-element, as this tells NHibernate that it's the child's responsibility to set the foreign key. And the child doesn't know about the list mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question you have to create a sequence in your database ([see description for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)), a simple example would be (might be different from database to database):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE item_no_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1
```

and then change your mapping a bit:

```
<id name="ItemNumber" type="integer" column="ITEM_NO">
  <generator class="sequence">
    <param name="sequence">item_no_seq</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```